# Instagram subscription webhook never called

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, webhooks

I created a subscription web hook for Instagram's API and can see it when listing subscriptions through the API:

```
[ { object: 'user',
    object_id: null,
    aspect: 'media',
    subscription_id: 0,
    callback_url: 'https://mydomain.cloudfront.net/v1/instagram/webhook',
    type: 'subscription',
    id: 0 } ]
```

My Instagram user is enabled as a sandbox API user.

I then sign up to my app using Instagram OAuth which works. I can see my app is listed on Instagram's website under "Authorized Applications".

I then use the Instagram app to post a picture. I would expect to see a call to `https://mydomain.cloudfront.net/v1/instagram/webhook` in my logs but am not seeing anything at all.

I've previously submitted my app for review but was denied (possibly due to a low quality screencast). Is is possible that the webhook stopped working because of that? Other API calls seem to work fine.

Comment: Have you solved it ? if yes, please post the solution.